# Change background and font color of different buttons when clicked on with CSS only. I tried :focus but only works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buttons need to change background and font color when are clicked on and back to original state when not

```css
button:focus {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Hello', this)" id="defaultOpen">Hello</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Bye', this)">Bye</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('See Ya', this)">See Ya</button>
```

I expected this to work on all browser but it only works in Chrome

Comment: works in firefox ... works in edge ... even works in IE

Comment: focus is probably lost with your openPage.

Comment: @JaromandaX it is actually OS dependent (as the [currently deleted answer by Connor Smyth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57422958/3702797) states). macOs for one doesn't allow buttons to have focus, so browsers generally follow this OS preference. Chrome only recently gone against this. (I learned it the hard way by participating in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1547926))

Comment: So i add snippet code but it it Still work maybe  `openPage('txt', this)` will made lost focused

Comment: so @Kaiido - it's not **browser** specific

Comment: It update snippet let test in other browser

Comment: @JaromandaX well... Chrome is the only one not  respecting this OS specific thing so yes, it's browser specific too

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear. From your first sentence, it sounds to me like you want the button to go black when you press down the mouse button, and turn white again when you release the mouse button. But then you say that the code you've already got works in Chrome. Yet in Chrome, the button styling doesn't go back to its original state until you tab off the button or click somewhere else - which seems to contradict your first sentence. Without a clearer description of what you want, we're left to guess.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a button you are targeting it is dependent on your operating system and/or browser for what the focus state will be.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `:active` property. For my understating while click you want to add background color and coming back with other page button background color should remain same?

Comment: active button it will trigger when clickdown when release will back to normally

Comment: You should use all browser prefix like --moz,, -webkit etc.

Comment: @RahulPathak What browsers do you think require a prefix? As far as I know `:active` has never had a vendor-prefixed form implemented in any version of any browser. Also, https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2 suggests that it's been implemented unprefixed in all browsers for over a decade.